# How to solve $x + \sqrt{x + \sqrt{11+x}}=11$ algebraically?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I solve the following equation algebraically?

$x + \sqrt{x + \sqrt{11+x}}=11$

Comment: The most straightforward way would be to subtract $x$ from both sides, and repeatedly square the equation until all you're left with are exponents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x-11=-\sqrt{x+\sqrt{11+x}}$. Square both sides to get $(x-11)^2=x+\sqrt{11+x}$.
Then $(x-11)^2-x=\sqrt{11+x}$ and you square again
$((x-11)^2-x)^2=11+x$. Unfortunately you get a 4th order equation. Try this [quartic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots)

Comment: R h s is 11 not 1.

Comment: changed it. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Using the same steps as Gio67 in his/her answer, we arrive to the following quartic equation
$$x^4-46 x^3+771 x^2-5567 x+14630=0$$ But, a (tedious) inspection shows that $x_1=14$ is a solution. However, this solution does not satisfy the original equation (it was introduced by the multiple squaring processes).

So, what remains is the cubic $$x^3-32 x^2+323 x-1045=0$$ the discriminant of which being $\Delta=5073$ which implies  three distinct real roots. Using the [trigonometric method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Trigonometric_solution_for_three_real_roots), the three roots are given by 
$$x_2=\frac{2\sqrt{55}}{3}  \cos (\theta )+\frac{32}{3}\approx 15.5500 $$
$$x_3=\sqrt{\frac{55}{3}} \sin (\theta )-\frac{\sqrt{55}}{3}  \cos (\theta
   )+\frac{32}{3}\approx 8.89430$$
$$x_4=-\sqrt{\frac{55}{3}} \sin (\theta )-\frac{\sqrt{55}}{3}  \cos (\theta
   )+\frac{32}{3}\approx 7.55568$$ where $$\theta=\frac{1}{3} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{9 \sqrt{1691}}{727}\right)\approx 0.156960$$ But, again, $x_2$ and $x_3$ do not satisfy the original equation.

So, the **only** root is $x_4\approx 7.55568$ which can be confirmed by a plot of the original function.

For sure, the plot showing a solution close to $x=7$, we could use Newton method using $$f(x)=x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+11}}-11$$ 
$$f'(x)=\frac{\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x+11}}+1}{2 \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+11}}}+1$$ and, starting with $x_0=7$, the successive iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 7.000000000 \\
 1 & 7.554554415 \\
 2 & 7.555683721 \\
 3 & 7.555683726
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for ten significant figures.

Comment: Interesting answer...

Comment: +1 by the effort (and probably the suffered pain) that imply the answer. This make me thing that life in the XIX century was so hard, lol.

Comment: @Masacroso I agree with you.

Comment: @Masacroso. Thank you ! May I confess that I cannot resist equations (hoping that I can solve them !).

Comment: Anyway, 14 is not a solution. Substitution $\sqrt{11+x}=t$ often helps. Unfortunately not in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Making the problem more general, that is to say solving for $x$ equation
$$x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{a+x}}=a$$ it is amazing to notice that a quite good estimate of the solution can be obtained using Newton method starting using $x_0=a$. The first iterate is given by $$x_1=a-\frac{8 \left(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{2}\right) a}{4\sqrt{a} \left(2 \sqrt{a+\sqrt{2a}
  }+1\right)+\sqrt{2}}$$ which is quite good as shown in the table.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a & x_1 & \text{exact}\\
 10 & 6.68080&6.71342\\
 20 & 15.3574& 15.3816\\
 30 & 24.3461&24.3662\\
 40 & 33.4949& 33.5126\\
 50 & 42.7457& 42.7617\\
 60 & 52.0688& 52.0835\\
 70 & 61.4466& 61.4603\\
 80 & 70.8677& 70.8806\\
 90 & 80.3241& 80.3363\\
 100 & 89.8100&89.8216
\end{array}
\right)$$ Using such an estimate (or even $x_0$), Newton method will converge to very high accuracy in very few iterations.

For the case od $a=11$, the iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 11.000000000000000000 \\
 1 & 7.5243730846179221178 \\
 2 & 7.5556803097191345483 \\
 3 & 7.5556837257172207418 \\
 4 & 7.5556837257172612872
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for twenty significant figures.

For very large values of $a$, the asymptotics of $x_1$ is given by 
$$x_1=a-\sqrt{a}+\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)+\frac{1}{4
   \sqrt{2a}}+\frac{1-\sqrt{2}}{8 a}+O\left(\frac{1}{a^{3/2}}\right)$$ For $a=1000$, this would give an estimate of $968.176$ while the exact solution would be $968.180$.